# How to make Superfish menu vertical in first level but horizontal in second level?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, superfish

I use Superfish menu within Drupal7 and my first item level is designed vertical. Now I want to style my second item level horizontal. How could I do this? I tried different CSS approaches, added some class names via jQuery like

$('first-level li')find('ul').addClass('sf-vertical');

but nothing helped. tnx!

edit: [here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/headkit/2vaQ3/3/) and my menu looks like

```
<ul id="superfish-1" class="sf-menu menu-page-menu sf-vertical sf-style-none sf-total-items-6 sf-parent-items-1 sf-single-items-5 sf-js-enabled">
    <li id="menu-622-1" class="first odd sf-item-1 sf-depth-1 sf-no-children">Item 1</li>
    <li id="menu-623-1" class="middle even sf-item-2 sf-depth-1 sf-total-children-5 sf-parent-children-0 sf-single-children-5 menuparent">Item 2
        <ul class="sf-vertical sf-hidden">
            <li id="menu-633-1" class="first odd sf-item-1 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children" style="white-space: normal; float: left; width: 100%; ">SubItem </li>
            <li id="menu-634-1" class="middle even sf-item-2 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children" style="white-space: normal; float: left; width: 100%; ">SubItem </li>
            <li id="menu-635-1" class="middle odd sf-item-3 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children" style="white-space: normal; float: left; width: 100%; ">SubItem </li>
            <li id="menu-636-1" class="middle even sf-item-4 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children" style="white-space: normal; float: left; width: 100%; ">SubItem </li>
            <li id="menu-637-1" class="last odd sf-item-5 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children" style="white-space: normal; float: left; width: 100%; ">SubItem </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-624-1" class="middle odd sf-item-3 sf-depth-1 sf-no-children">Item 3</li>
    <li id="menu-625-1" class="middle even sf-item-4 sf-depth-1 sf-no-children">Item 4</li>
    <li id="menu-626-1" class="middle odd sf-item-5 sf-depth-1 sf-no-children">Item 5</li>
    <li id="menu-627-1" class="last even sf-item-6 sf-depth-1 sf-no-children">Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try putting your code in a jsfiddle or similar or this will likely be closed.

Comment: @Kiz added jsFiddle and some code.

Comment: Did you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/headkit/2vaQ3/3/

Comment: what did you change? can't see any difference. what I want is that the second level menu (item2) opens as horizontal menu left beside the first level item that is hovered over. in my example the second level menu opens as vertical menu (same as first level).

Comment: Sorry here: http://jsfiddle.net/TC9hy/

Comment: no. can't see any changing behaviour. maybe you need to save your changes?

Comment: Did you use the new link I posted?

Comment: yes, I did. the second level also opens as vertical menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the fix width of `.sf-menu ul li ul` and `.sf-menu ul ul li` remove `width:100%` and give `margin_right:XXpx;`

CSS like

```
.sf-menu ul li ul{width:400px;}
.sf-menu ul ul li{float:left; margin-right:10px;}
```

Comment: thanx for your help. unfortunately it doesn't work. did you try this within the jsfiddle?

Comment: I built another menu from ground up and I found out that your width-hint did the trick. so I mark this answer as correct. thnx! here is my JSBin: http://jsbin.com/egowof/2/edit